# Passing datetime as an array in SOAP API PHP

Tags: php, api, soap

I have a function like this for a SOAP call for a GetSchedule REQUEST.

```
public function GetSchedule(array $sessionTypeIDs, array $startDate , array $endDate)
```

I usually pass it from my controller like this

```
$result1 = $bookservice->GetSchedule(array(114,115,116,127), array(2017-09-25), array(2017-10-15);
```

When I try to pass dates like this, it gives me a FORBIDDEN error

> SoapFault Forbidden
>
> ---

How can I pass dates properly? I am using Laravel and I am trying to make a SOAP call. It's working fine if I don't supply anything for $startDate and $endDate, but if try to filter it by these two variables, I get a Forbidden error.

Comment: have you tried to quote the dates?

Comment: Yes, I tried quoting the dates, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in a number, since you're not quoting the date it's doing the math  (1983). Instead, you need to quote it.

```
$result1 = $bookservice->GetSchedule(array(114,115,116,127), array('2017-09-25'), array('2017-10-15');
```

Comment: In that case, you may want to double-check the documentation. There may be more that you need to pass into that array. If it's an API that you're creating, then you may need to double-check everything that you're passing in, along with the route.

Comment: A `Forbidden` error also usually comes down to an authentication error.